# How to merge two ppt by poi

Tags: merge, copy, apache-poi, powerpoint

I want to merge multiple ppts. I use POI realize most functions, but there are still some problems. Some elements are not generated. I tested several groups of ppts.

Case 1: If there is only one slide in the PPT, the result is right. If there are multiple slides, will throw exception.
Below is the exception stack:
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart cannot be cast to org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFPictureData
at org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSheet.importBlip(XSLFSheet.java:649)
at org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFPictureShape.copy(XSLFPictureShape.java:378)
at org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSheet.wipeAndReinitialize(XSLFSheet.java:454)
at org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSheet.importContent(XSLFSheet.java:433)
at org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSlide.importContent(XSLFSlide.java:294)
at com.office.MergingMultiplePresentations.main(MergingMultiplePresentations.java:38)

Case 2: I tested another PPT, and when I opened it, it prompted “there is a problem with the content, you can try to repair it“”. When I click repair, the some slide of the PPT was deleted. Is there something that hasn't been copied?

Here is my code:

```
    XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow();
    //taking the two presentations that are to be merged
    String path = "E:\\prj\\test\\";
    String file1 = "1.pptx";
    String file2 = "2.pptx";
    String[] inputs = {file1,file2};

    for(String arg : inputs){

        FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(path+arg);
        XMLSlideShow src = new XMLSlideShow(inputstream);
        for(XSLFSlide srcSlide : src.getSlides()) {
           try {
                XSLFSlideLayout srcLayout = srcSlide.getSlideLayout();
                XSLFSlideMaster srcMaster = srcSlide.getSlideMaster();

                XSLFSlide slide = ppt.createSlide();

                XSLFSlideLayout layout = slide.getSlideLayout();
                XSLFSlideMaster master = slide.getSlideMaster();

                layout.importContent(srcLayout);
                master.importContent(srcMaster);
                slide.importContent(srcSlide);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
    String file3 = "3.pptx";

    //creating the file object
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path+file3);
    // saving the changes to a file
    ppt.write(out);
    out.close();
```

Comment: The error is not about one slide per slideshow vs. multiple slides. The error is about not able to cast a  `POIXMLDocumentPart ` to `XSLFPictureData` in `XSLFSheet.importBlip`. So in one of the source slideshows there is a picture shape containing a blip fill which is not correctly linked to ity picture data in media directory of the `*.pptx` ZIP archive. So to reproduce one would need the source slideshows.

Comment: Btw.: The error will disappear if you update to `apache poi 5.1.*` or later. There `XMLSlideShow.importBlip` does a type check before trying to cast. But of course there are multiple other issues with merging any kind of Office Open XML files because of the complex internally structure of the underlying ZIP archives.

Comment: Thanks @AxelRichter.When i update to apache poi 5.2.2, the issue of exception was fixed I have another problem. I tested another PPT, and when I opened it, it prompted “there is a problem with the content, you can try to repair it“”. When I click repair, the some slide of the PPT was deleted. Is there something that hasn't been copied?

Comment: Told already: Of course there are multiple other issues with merging any kind of Office Open XML files. I doubt there are libraries which are able doing this 100% correct except Microsoft Office itself.

Answer (score 0):

The operation of merging presentations using POI looks a bit cumbersome due to the fact that you have to take care of the layouts and masters yourself. It's easier to use [Aspose.Slides for Java](https://products.aspose.com/slides/java/) for this. The following code example shows you how to merge presentations using that library. Slide layouts and slide masters will be merged automatically.

```java
String file1 = "1.pptx";
String file2 = "2.pptx";
String[] inputs = {file1, file2};

// Prepare a new empty presentation.
Presentation ppt = new Presentation();
ppt.getSlides().removeAt(0); // removes the first empty slide
ppt.getSlideSize().setSize(SlideSizeType.Widescreen, SlideSizeScaleType.Maximize);

// Merge the input presentations.
for (String file : inputs) {
    Presentation source = new Presentation(file);
    for (ISlide slide : source.getSlides()) {
        ppt.getSlides().addClone(slide);
    }
    source.dispose();
}

ppt.save("3.pptx", SaveFormat.Pptx);
ppt.dispose();
```

This is a paid product, but you can get a temporary license to try it out.

Alternatively, you could use [Aspose.Slides Cloud SDK for Java](https://products.aspose.cloud/slides/java/). This product provides a REST-based API that allows you to make 150 free API calls per month for API learning and presentation processing. The following code example shows you how to do the same using Aspose.Slides Cloud:

```java
SlidesApi slidesApi = new SlidesApi("my_client_id", "my_client_secret");

String file1 = "1.pptx";
String file2 = "2.pptx";
String outFile = "3.pptx";

// Prepare a new empty presentation.
slidesApi.createPresentation(outFile, null, null, null, null, null);
slidesApi.deleteSlide(outFile, 1, null, null, null); // removes the first empty slide

SlideProperties slideProperties = new SlideProperties();
slideProperties.setSizeType(SlideProperties.SizeTypeEnum.WIDESCREEN);
slideProperties.setScaleType(SlideProperties.ScaleTypeEnum.MAXIMIZE);
slidesApi.setSlideProperties(outFile, slideProperties, null, null, null);

// Merge the input presentations.
PresentationsMergeRequest mergeRequest = new PresentationsMergeRequest();
mergeRequest.setPresentationPaths(Arrays.asList(file1, file2));
slidesApi.merge(outFile, mergeRequest, null, null, null);
```

Sometimes it is necessary to merge presentations without any code. For such cases, you can use the free [Aspose Online Merger](https://products.aspose.app/slides/merger).

I work as a Support Developer at Aspose.